# Template interface return types

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a template, which should be used as an interface to implement. This kind of thing is easy on Java, but I am fighting C++. The code does not compile in the `C2::action()` method. It seems the compiler thinks I am trying to allocate an abstract type.

Am I missing a copy constructor... or... what?

```
template <class T> 
class C1 {
public:
    virtual C1<T> action() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class C2: public C1<T> {
public:
    virtual C1<T> action(){
        C2<T> sub;
        return sub;
    }

};

C2<int> t;
t.action();
```

Comment: This question could use an error message to be a better [mcve]

Comment: c++ is not java, what you return is not a reference but an actual object. You cannot create objects of abstract classes

Comment: I suggest you to drop the template for a moment, because what is wrong on your code is orthogonal to using templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C1<T> action()` returns an object of type `C1<T>`. Since `C1<T>` is abstract, you can never succeed in returning from `action`. Even if you try to initialize this return value with concrete type like `C2<T>` it will experience [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and "turn into" a `C1<T>` (or try to). This tries to construct a `C1<T>` based on your `C2<T>`. But since `C1<T>` is abstract it can't be constructed.

To enable polymorphism you need to rely on references or pointers. While a `C1<T>` is always a `C1<T>`, a `C1<T>*` can point to an object of type `C1<T>` or any other type that inherits publically form it such as `C2<T>`. You could try returning a `std::unique_ptr<C1<T>>` instead of `C1<T>` :

```
#include <memory>

template <class T> 
class C1 {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<C1<T>> action() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class C2: public C1<T> {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<C1<T>> action() override {
        return std::make_unique<C2<T>>();
    }

};
```